# writing logic to store data in Mysql to store Metadata of Files

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, logic

Lemme explain the scenario:
I need to fetch all the Metadata of Files, i.e., Title, author, subject.. and Custom Attributes.( Custom attributes are not fixed, they are not fixed and can be of any numbers).

Now to Store this Struvture I have Designed a DB like :
MainTable:
FileID, FileName, Title, Author, Subject

and To Store Custom Attributes ( As there numbers and names are not fixed)

(Store Custom Attribute Names)
Table AttrType:
AttrID, AttrName, AttrType(String or numbers)

(Store Custome Attribute Values)
and Table AttrValues:
FileID, AttrId, AttrValue.

Now I get all the Meta of Files writte nin files and I need to Write some logic, so that I can put proper data in Proper tables.
I am totaly stucked, dont know where and how to start.
Is there anybody who can help me.

I would be highly thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You need an external program in some programming language to do these things. A database is to store data, not a general purpose programming language like Java, Python or C.